# Proving Complex Function on Provided Unbounded Domain Has the Same Sup on Interior and Boundary

Tags: complex-analysis

Problem statement:

Let $\Omega=\{z\in\mathbb{C}: 0<\text{Re} z<1\}.$ Assume $f$ is bounded and continuous on $\bar{\Omega}$ and holomorphic on $\Omega$. Show that
$$\sup_\Omega |f|=\sup_{\partial\Omega} |f|.$$

I was given the following hint: For $\epsilon>0$, consider $f_\epsilon (z)=f(z)e^{\epsilon z^2}.$
Relax the hypothesis that $f$ is bounded.

I haven't been able to make much headway, so I was hoping for a further hint (not a solution). I'm not clear on exact what the hint is saying when it says to relax the hypothesis. I think it's saying that if I try a proof by contradiction, I'll get that $f$ is unbounded.

If $f$ is constant, then the result is clear, so suppose not. Evidently, $f_\epsilon$ is holomorphic on $\Omega$ and continuous on $\bar{\Omega}.$ It is also non-constant (as we assume $f$ is non-constant), so by the contrapositive of the maximum modulus principal, there is no $z_0\in\Omega$ for which $|f_\epsilon(z_0)|\geq |f_\epsilon(z)|,$ where $z\in\Omega$ in arbitrary. I'm not really sure what, if anything, to do with this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [Phragmén–Lindelöf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phragm%C3%A9n%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_principle) type result.

Assume that $|f(z)| \le K$ for $z \in \Omega$ and  $|f(z)| \le M$
for $z \in \partial \Omega$. The goal is to show that 
$|f(z)| \le M$ for all $z \in \Omega$.

*Hints (as requested):* For $\epsilon > 0$ define $f_\epsilon (z)=f(z)e^{\epsilon z^2}$. Then
$$ \tag{*}
|f_\epsilon (z)|=|f(z)|e^{\operatorname{Re}\epsilon z^2}
 = |f(z)| e^{\epsilon (x^2 - y^2)} \le |f(z)| e^{\epsilon (1 - y^2)}
$$
for $z = x + iy$. Now investigate $f_\epsilon$ on a rectangle
$$
 R_s =  \{ z \mid 0 \le \operatorname{Re} z \le 1, -s \le \operatorname{Im} z
 \le s \}
$$
for fixed $s > 0$. Use $(*)$ to obtain estimates for $f_\epsilon$
on the boundary of $R$, and apply the maximum principle to conclude
that
$$
 |f_\epsilon (z)| \le \max(M e^{\epsilon}, K e^{\epsilon(1-s^2)})
$$
in the rectangle $R_s$. For sufficiently large $s$ it follows that
$|f_\epsilon (z)| \le M e^{\epsilon}$  in $R_s$ and thus in $\Omega$.

The conclusion then follows by letting $\epsilon \to 0$.

Finally, the hypothesis that $f$ is bounded can be relaxed by a 
condition that $f(x+iy)$ does now grow "too fast" for $|y| \to \infty$.

Comment: Awesome, the rectangle idea is precisely what I needed. Thanks!